# How do I randomly set the color for a MovieClip in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to randomly set the color for a MovieClip in ActionScript 3.  How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

**Example with some colors in a array:**

```
var colorArray:Array = new Array(0xFFFF33, 0xFFFFFF, 0x79DCF4, 0xFF3333, 0xFFCC33, 0x99CC33);
var randomColorID:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length);

var myColor:ColorTransform = this.transform.colorTransform;
myColor.color=colorArray[randomColorID];

myMovieClip.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
```

Change the myMovieClip to the instance name oof your movie clip, if you want you could add a click event to change the random colors.

Answer (score 0):

I know your post is old, but i just figured this out.
You don't need to create your own color array, you can steal it from the colorpicker.

```
import fl.controls.*;
var _lineWeight:Number = 20;
var cp:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();

var randomNumber:Number = Math.random() * cp.colors.length;

var drawing:Shape = new Shape();
drawing.graphics.lineStyle(_lineWeight,cp.colors[randomNumber]);
```